Maximum recursion depth exceeded issue in Postman
def inactive_customer_cohorts(startDate, endDate):
try:
    print("startDate : ", startDate)
    print("endDate : ", endDate)

    df = data_util.get_customer_scans_df(startDate, endDate)
    columns = ['userId', 'createdAt']

    df = df[columns]
    df['scanQuater'] = ('Q' + df['createdAt'].dt.quarter.astype(str) + '/' + df['createdAt'].dt.year.astype(str))

    quartersMap = dict(zip(df['scanQuater'].unique(), range(len(df['scanQuater'].unique()))))

    scanQuarterUsers = df.groupby('scanQuater')['userId'].apply(list).reset_index()
    scanQuarterUsers['length'] = scanQuarterUsers['userId'].apply(len)


    quarterUsers = {row['scanQuater']: row['userId'] for _, row in scanQuarterUsers.iterrows()}
    quarters = list(quartersMap.keys())

    cumulativePreviousUserIds = set()
    previousQuarterUserMap = {}
    
    data = []
    for i in range(len(quarters)):
        currentQuarter = quarters[i]
        if currentQuarter in quarterUsers:
            nonUniquecurrentUserIds = quarterUsers[currentQuarter]
            currentUserIds = set(quarterUsers[currentQuarter])
            currentCount = len(currentUserIds)
            nonUniqueCurrentCount = len(nonUniquecurrentUserIds)
         
            if cumulativePreviousUserIds:
                uniqueCommonUserIds = set()
                quarterCommonCounts = {}
                for prevQuarter, prevUserIds in previousQuarterUserMap.items():
                    specificCommonUserIds = currentUserIds.intersection(prevUserIds)
                    for userId in specificCommonUserIds:
                        if userId not in uniqueCommonUserIds:
                            uniqueCommonUserIds.add(userId)
                            if prevQuarter in quarterCommonCounts:
                                quarterCommonCounts[prevQuarter] += 1
                            else:
                                quarterCommonCounts[prevQuarter] = 1

                previousQuartersSummary = ", ".join([f"{count} from {quarter}" for quarter, count in quarterCommonCounts.items()])
                totalSpecificCommonCount = len(uniqueCommonUserIds)
                newUsers = currentCount - totalSpecificCommonCount

                data.append({
                        "quarter": currentQuarter,
                        "scanCount": nonUniqueCurrentCount,
                        "uniqueCounts": currentCount,
                        "common": totalSpecificCommonCount,
                        "new": newUsers,
                        "common_breakdown": previousQuartersSummary
                    })
            else:
                data.append({
                    "quarter": currentQuarter,
                    "scanCount": nonUniqueCurrentCount,
                    "uniqueCounts": currentCount,
                    "common": 0,
                    "new": currentCount,
                    "common_breakdown": ""
                })

            cumulativePreviousUserIds.update(currentUserIds)
            previousQuarterUserMap[currentQuarter] = currentUserIds
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    return df   
except Exception as e:
    common_util.error_logs(e, 'inactive_customer_cohorts')
    raise e
            

This is the code I'm trying to run, whenever I run this code normally without any flask or postman, I get a proper output. But whenever I try to run it through postman, I get the following error :
 {
 "status": 500,
 "message": "maximum recursion depth exceeded",
 "data": {}
 }

Please let me know what should I do to avoid getting this error. Let me know if more info is needed.

You need to look at the stacktrace, it'll will explain it to you

Likely one of your functions calls itself inadvertently. What is the name of your flask view function? Perhaps you named the flask view function inactive_customer_cohorts as well? If that is the case, the view function will just call itself over and over, resulting in this error.

see @codeape
class CustomerCohorts(Resource):  def post(self):   try:    startDate = request.form["startDate"]    endDate = request.form["endDate"]                         common_util.check_if_present(startDate, endDate)    inActiveCustomerCohorts = util.inactive_customer_cohorts(startDate, endDate)    response = {'status': 200, 'message': 'FCT ML data listed', 'data': inActiveCustomerCohorts} return api.make_response(response, 200) except custom_exception.UserException as e: common_util.error_logs(e, 'CustomerCohorts.post') response = {'status': 500, 'message': str(e), 'data':{}

Examining the stack trace should give you information on which function is causing the recursion. From your code sample, I guess the problem is either the inadvertently-calling-itself-problem (check functions inactive_customer_cohorts and check_if_present and make_response). Another problem could be that the data that you return (inActiveCustomerCohorts) contains cycles.
